# Storing dictionary into Jinja template

Tags: python, python-3.x, templates, jinja2

I have stored data into dictionary. Now I am not getting how to use it into jinja template for getting expected output. I have tried to fetch but it is not working.

This is my dictionary:

```
{
  "Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN": [
    {
      "b": 102,
      "c": "",
      "d": "Nokia_SRAN_mobility_platinum",
      "e": "h1",
      "f": 7,
      "g": "dscp-fc-map",
      "h": [
        "ef",
        "nc1"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Nodeb_IN_New": [
    {
      "b": 107,
      "c": "class-default",
      "d": "mobility-platinum",
      "e": "h1",
      "f": 7,
      "g": "dscp-fc-map",
      "h": [
        "ef"
      ]
    },
    {
      "b": 107,
      "c": "",
      "d": "mobility-gold-new",
      "e": "h2",
      "f": 5,
      "g": "dscp-fc-map",
      "h": [
        "af41"
      ]
    },
    {
      "b": 107,
      "c": "",
      "d": "mobility-silver-new",
      "e": "l1",
      "f": 4,
      "g": "dscp-fc-map",
      "h": [
        "af11",
        "af21",
        "af31"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my JINJA Template which I tried.

```
/configure qos 
{%-for k,v in data.items()%}
    {%-if (v['nokia'])|length>0%}
    {{v['nokia']}} {{v['policy_id']}} create
            description "{{k}}"
            {%-for i in range(0,(v['dscp'])|length)%}
            dscp {{v['dscp'][i]}} fc "{{v['mpls']}}"
            {%endfor%}
            {%-if v['default'] != ''%}
            {v['default']}
            {%endif%}
        exit
    {%endif%}
        ingress-cos-policy {{v['policy_id']}} create
            description "{{k}}"
            enable-dscp-exp-remarking
            {{v['nokia']}} {{v['policy_id']}}
        exit

        sap-ingress {{v['policy_id']}} create
            description "{{k}}"
            ingress-cos-policy {{v['policy_id']}}
    {%-for j in queue%}
            policer {{queue}} create
            exit
    {%-endfor%}
    {%-for j,l in zip(queue,v['dscp'])%}
            fc "{{v['dscp']}}" create
                policer {{queue}}
            exit
    {%-endfor%}
        exit           
{%-endfor%}
```

My expected output should be like this:

```
/configure qos
        dscp-fc-map 100 create
            description "Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN"
            dscp ef fc "h1"
            dscp nc1 fc "h1"
        exit


        ingress-cos-policy 100 create
            description "Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN"
            enable-dscp-exp-remarking
            dscp-fc-map 100
        exit

        sap-ingress 100 create
            description "Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN"
            ingress-cos-policy 100
            policer 7 create 
            exit
            fc "h1" create
                policer 7
            exit
        exit

-----------------
/configure qos
        dscp-fc-map 101 create
            description "Nodeb_IN_New"
            dscp ef fc "h1"
            dscp af11 fc "l1"
            dscp af21 fc "l1"
            dscp af31 fc "l1"
            dscp af41 fc "h2"
            default-fc be   
        exit

        ingress-cos-policy 101 create
            description "Nodeb_IN_New"
            enable-dscp-exp-remarking
            dscp-fc-map 101
        exit


        sap-ingress 101 create
            description "Nodeb_IN_New"
            ingress-cos-policy 101
            policer 7 create
            exit
            policer 5 create
            exit
            policer 4 create
            exit
            fc "h1" create
                policer 7
            exit
            fc "h2" create
                policer 5
            exit
            fc "l1" create
                policer 4
            exit
        exit
```

Need help to get output as expected.

Comment: Please use a very small dictionary (e.g. two keys) and a very small template (4 lines) to test and add the code here if the problem is still there. Then we can help you.